# ge washing machine sticks at rinse cycle

Tags: repair

Was having issues with GE washing machine not draining or spinning so I replaced timer and lid switch now after the wash cycle the timer sticks and won't advance to the rinse cycle. If you turn the knob slightly after this happens it fills with water and finishes the cycle. It doesn't seem to matter what wash cycle you choose it does the same thing. Any ideas?

Comment: A model number might be useful.  As a guess, I would say there is a sensor that detects when the tub has emptied that isn't working.   The washer fills and runs (and drains?) but doesn't know that the tub has drained and it should go to the next step.

Comment: please provide model details: *, top/front loader, age. A picture of the back and front of the old switch would help.